# How to quickly delete many entities programmatically?

Tags: performance, 10, entity

This appears to be the prescribed way of deleting multiple node entities:

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->accessCheck(FALSE)
  ->condition('field_my_field', 'something')
  ->execute();

$storage_handler = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');

$entities = $storage_handler->loadMultiple($nids);

$storage_handler->delete($entities);
```

However, this takes a long time to execute.  On my machine, the above code takes about 15 minutes to delete 100 entities.  The same machine can programmatically create 100 entities in about 40 seconds -- not blazingly fast, but acceptable.

I also tried looping through the $nids to load and delete them one at a time.  That runs about 10% faster, perhaps because the memory is released after each load.  Still, it's too slow.

The relevant content type has about 30 fields. Perhaps this is a factor.

What if my application requires regularly deleting hundreds of entities, and it isn't practical to wait over an hour for the script to execute?  Is there some other option for deleting large numbers of entities?

Drupal 10.2.3.  PHP 8.1.16.  MariaDB 10.4.28.

Comment: Is Drush an option? https://www.drush.org/12.x/commands/entity_delete/

Comment: It is hard to say here why deleting these individual entities is so slow. You may have to PHP profile to figure that out. As for processing large amounts of items offline, Drupal's queue API is the usual way and it is fully documented.

Comment: @leymannx  Drush takes just as long -- about 15 minutes for 100 nodes.  I suspect it runs the same code as I posted in my question.

Comment: @cilefen  The issue is the amount of time that passes between initiating the deletions and when the deletions have completed.  Thus, processing it offline won't help.

Comment: I updated my question to mention the content type has 30 fields.  I wonder if this is a factor.  Though I would think that would be just as much a factor when creating the nodes, and it only takes 40 seconds to create 100 nodes.

Comment: Whenever I suggest PHP profiling it tends to be ignored.

Comment: Yeah just to double down on that - you need to profile _your_ site to find out why it takes so long to do something. Asking for people to guess from afar isn’t going to work for something like this. 40 seconds to create 100 nodes is very slow by today’s standards BTW. My 6 year old laptop takes less than 10 seconds to do the same, for comparison. But that’s on a site which doesn’t have any bottlenecks for entity deletion, which is the whole point - The problem is very narrowly scoped to your site and its implementation, it needs to be debugged by someone with full access to it

Comment: To fully answer the question: no, there are no quicker ways to mass-delete entities in a Drupal site; none that could be considered as safe, anyway, as the hooks/events need to run. You can improve your memory usage by using an entity query, chunking the loop, and resetting the storage cache after each iteration, but that’s not going to make your processors work faster, and it’s not going to reduce the number of expensive operations your site appears to be doing on delete.